# Is this the correct mean/average for this question

Tags: statistics, means

I know this is a simple question but wanted to make sure as a sanity check that I am not missing some detail. I tend to read things too fast and want to make sure I am providing the information that is wanted.

QUESTION:
[image]

MY SOLUTION:
Simply taking the average of the frequencies (counts) and then dividing my the number of items.

(518+451+210+72+59+12) / 6 = 220.33...

It would appear that the average is 220.33 therefore the commute time would fall between 210 to 451. Not entirely sure how to make that timeframe more exact for a time frame. All I know is that for sum range of time the number 220.33 of people cluster in that range. Somewhere from  30-44 to 15-29. I feel like I am missing a crucial detail somewhere here.

Thank you

Comment: This isn't correct.  The people who take a long time get to work contribute more to the average (per individual) than the people who take a short time.  Ask yourself, how would you compute the average time if you knew how long it takes each individual to get to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The average commute time will be the average commute time in each row times the percentage of the populations in that row.

$$7(.3918) + 22(.3411)+37(.1589)+52(.0545)+67(.0446)+82(.0091)= 22.6945$$

Comment: Thank you. Why does this work? I don't understand it. Does this formula have a name? Also I see where the percentages are coming from but how are you getting the averages 7,22,37.

Comment: Yes, it is the formula for the mean of a distribution.  $\overline x  = \sum xp(x) $

Comment: These numbers 7,22,37 are the average commute time for each row. For example the first row has the average (0+14)/2 = 7.

Comment: Thank you. Would this also be called the weighted average? Also, I thought for the average we would have to consider all the number in between such as 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14, then add all those up and divide by 15. It confuses me why it would be 0 plus 14 isn't it ranging from 0 to 14 so shouldn't we include all that data between the two.

Comment: Yes it is also called the weighted average. If you average numbers from 0 to 14 you get the same as 7. The sum is 105 and when you divide by 15 you get 7. It is easier to just average the endpoints.

Comment: Thanks so anytime we are dealing with little data-sets like these which have varying levels of percentages the way in which we would find the average of the entire data-set is to do a weighted-average?

Comment: Correct, that is it.